# Open non-Makefile project with existing code in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse

I have a C++ project that does not use make for building.  It is a Git clone.  I need to be able to open this project in Eclipse.  I could delete the directory and import from the Git repository.  I was wondering, is there a way to do this with the existing directory and files?

Comment: I'm not quite getting what you're saying, So you have the git clone set up on your local drive, and you want to open that in eclipse . So when you make changes in eclipse it updated the github file and you justn end to git push it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure Eclipse for Git integration.

Use this tutorial in order to configure EGit

[EclipseGit](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGit/article.html)

If you have the C++ project (not the Git cloned one)

File > Import> General > Existing projects into workspace

Set the root directory to where your .project and .cproject files are located.